# Disable stepping into property declarations while debugging in Xcode

Tags: objective-c, xcode, debugging

Is there any way to disable stepping into every single property reference while debugging in Xcode? I'm talking about automatically synthesized properties, not ones with custom getters/setters.

By default Xcode "steps" into the property declaration in the .h file, which is frankly completely useless and a waste of time. If a particular method call takes several properties as parameters and all I want to do is step into the method, I have to step in, step out, step in, step out, step in, step out and step in again, just to get through all those bloody properties.

It's just plain annoying.

Comment: The obvious technique is to command-click on the method name to jump to that in the editor, press command+\ to set a breakpoint there and then continue execution (e.g. command+control+`y`). I know it's not what you're looking for, but the sequence is pretty quick and skips over those accessor methods.